# Check if item exists in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview

I have this code:

```
    <Page.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="IconTextDataTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="220" Height="60" Background="#FF729FD4">
                    <Border Background="#66727272" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="10">
                        <Image Source="/SampleImage.png" Height="32" Width="32" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
    <ListView x:Name="Name" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IconTextDataTemplate}"   Grid.Row="6" Margin="40,20,40,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="White" SelectionChanged="DoSomething">
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="4"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListView>
```

And another `ListView` with the same properties with another `x:Name`. I need to copy the items from one `ListView` to another.

I have a code that do it, my question is how can I check if the item in one `ListView` already copied to the second `ListView`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want if the name has allready been added you can use linq like this

```
if(!listView2.Items.Any(item => item.Name == theNameToCheck))
{
     //copy item
}
```

`Contains()` would require you to have have `IEquatable` Implemented by the class of the `ListViews` items:

```
class Test : IEquatable<Test>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Test other)
    {
        return other.Name == this.Name;
    }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
if(!listView2.Items.Contains(theItem))
{
     listView2.Items.Add(theItem);
}
```

That is unless you really have the same instance of the class and not a copy of the class (another object with the same properties)

Comment: @Tal is there a problem?

Comment: `listview.Items.Contains(SearchItem); ` doesn't work in wpf. IS Contains method not applicable in wpf?  

Please provide the equivalent code to search duplication in WPF

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you just give a simple list to the listviews:

```
listView1.Items = myItemList;
```

and you use the same list to copy the elements to the second listview, you could simply do this:

```
MyItem itemToCopy = listView1.SelectedItem; //Or where ever your item comes from

if(!listView2.Items.contains(itemToCopy)
{
    listView2.Items.add(itemToCopy);
}
else
{
    // Item is already in the list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, you got two lists.
You copy from one to the other, after that you can go trought that new list with a foreach loop.
I think it should look like that:

```
bool found = false;

foreach(ListviewItem originalItem in myOriginalList.Items)
{
    foreach(ListViewItem copiedItem in myNewList.Items)
    {
         //Check for equality between both items
         if(originalItem.Text == copiedItem.Text)
         {
              found = true;
              break;
         }

    }
    //Check if the entry is found
    if(found == false)
    {
         //TRY TO COPY AGAIN
    }
    //Set the bool back
    found = false;
}
```