# How to check if an element was erased?

Tags: c#, list, xamarin, ui-testing

I have a pets list and I'm erasing a pet from the list 
how can I verify that the pet was erased?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check if object already exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435089/how-to-check-if-object-already-exists-in-a-list)

Comment: in an app like: waitforelement or waitfornoelement

Answer (score 0):

You can verify by using contain method. If(!petList.Contains("erasedPet"))

Comment: I have a listview in an app and I want to check if the text(the pet's name) not appearing anymore

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624330/check-if-item-exists-in-listview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove that text from any item of the list, you can make a query to have items with that text then remove them from the list.

```
var removingList = pets.Where(p => p.Name == petName).Tolist();

foreach(var pet in removingList)
{
    pets.Remove(pet);
}
```